# Сгенерируйте серию случайных чисел из 0, 1, 2 так, чтобы количество двоек было равно количеству нулей

Tags: c#

> Сгенерируйте серию случайных чисел из 0, 1, 2 так, чтобы количество двоек было равно количеству нулей без массива.

Помогите пожалуйста доделать вот эту задачу! У меня не выходит парное количество двое и нулей.

Вот что я сделал :

```
while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Введите кол-во цифр: ");
                int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (num < 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Не меньше трёх!!!!!");
                    continue;
                }

                Random rnd = new Random();
                int a = rnd.Next(1, (num + 1) / 2);
                int b = a;
                int c = num - a * 2;

                int count = num;
                while (count > 0)
                {
                    int s = rnd.Next(0, 3 + 1);
                    if (s == 0 && c > 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write(0 + " ");
                        c--;
                        count--;
                    }
                    if (s == 1 && a > 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write(1 + " ");
                        a--;
                        count--;
                    }
                    if (s == 2 && b > 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write(2 + " ");
                        b--;
                        count--;
                    }

                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

Буду благодарен за любой ответ!

Comment: num это длинна серии ? а может быть серия где не будут только единицы ? по условию получается так

Comment: Да,num это длина серии . По условию там должно быть так : например я ввел длину серии 6 , должно получиться так : 010122 (это например)

Answer (score 3):

Чисто ради разнообразия, добавлю немного итераторов

```
Console.Write("Введите кол-во цифр: ");
int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

var rnd = new Random();
var twoAndZero = rnd.Next(num/2+1); 
var onesCount = Math.Max(0, num - twoAndZero * 2);

var result = Enumerable.Repeat("1", onesCount)
    .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("0", twoAndZero))
    .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("2", twoAndZero))
    .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())
    .Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Агрегат быть может `x + " " + y` должен быть?

Comment: Может быть и так :)

Answer (score 0):

вот так попробуйте

```
      while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите кол-во цифр: ");
            int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            // можно и 3 только вот чтоб было обязательно один 1 и вариант ниже в 
            // комбинации
            // можно и 2 только чтоб было либо 0,2 либо 2,0
            // либо 1,1
            // и вариант только 1
            if (num < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите положительное число!!!!!");
                continue;
            }

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int diff = 0;
            
            int count = num;
            while (count > 0)
            {
                int s = rnd.Next(0, 3 + 1);
                if (s == 0 && (count - Math.Abs(diff + 1)) > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(0 + " ");
                    diff++;
                    count--;
                }
                if (s == 1 && (count - Math.Abs(diff)) > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(1 + " ");
                    count--;
                }
                if (s == 2 && (count - Math.Abs(diff - 1)) > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(2 + " ");
                    diff--;
                    count--;
                }

            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Эх, чем еще в субботу не заняться, как не школьными задачками :-)

```
    var random = new Random();

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите кол-во цифр: ");
        int length = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (length < 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Не меньше трёх!!!!!");
            continue;
        }

        var zeroCount = 0;
        var twoCount = 0;
        var totalLength = 0;

        while (totalLength < length)
        {
            var curNum = random.Next(0, 3);

            var curSpace = length - totalLength;
            var needTwo = zeroCount > twoCount  ? zeroCount - twoCount : 0;
            var needZero = twoCount > zeroCount ? twoCount - zeroCount : 0;

            var k = 1;
            if (needZero == 0 && needTwo == 0)
                k = 2;

            if (curNum == 0 && needZero == 0 && needZero + needTwo + (needTwo - needZero + k)  > curSpace)
                continue;

            if (curNum == 2 && needTwo == 0 && needZero + needTwo + (needZero - needTwo + k) > curSpace)
                continue;

            if (curNum == 1 && length - totalLength <= needZero + needTwo)
                continue;

            if (curNum == 0)
                zeroCount++;

            if (curNum == 2)
                twoCount++;

            Console.Write($"{curNum} ");

            totalLength++;
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
```